# conditional scrollIntoView based on screen position

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I'd like to scroll to `MessageCell` under two conditions. If its a new message populated via Redux and the user hasn't scrolled too far into the older messages (the new message is x pixels away from the displayed portion of the scroll view.

With my current setup, the scroll view automatically scrolls every time a message comes in.

**Update:** I have no issue with my current code base (if you see an issue with my current approach feel free to point it out) What I'm looking for is a plan of attack. I'm a bit stumped on how to approach this problem.

```
class scrollView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setScrollSectionRef = this.setScrollSectionRef.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            scrollSection: null,
        };
    }
    setScrollSectionRef(node) {
        const { scrollSection } = this.state;
        this.scrollSection = node;
        // this is to force a re-render of messages
        // for them to recive the scrollSectionRef
        if (!scrollSection) {
            this.setState({ scrollSection: this.scrollSection });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section ref={this.setScrollSectionRef} className="threadMessageListContainer">
                <ul className="threadMessageList">
                    {
                        this.props.data.map((data) =>
                            <MessageCell
                                key={data.id}
                                scrollSection={scrollSection}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

class MessageCell extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setLIref = this.setLIref.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Auto scroll window to bottom of scrollView feed
        if (this.liRef) {
            this.liRef.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
    setLIref(node) {
        this.liRef = node;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li
                ref={this.setLIref}
                className={cellClasses}
            >
                some displayed data
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the Redux code?

Comment: @ShawnAndrews My redux code is quite lengthy. But all that is happening there is whenever a user posts a message I receive an action via a socket that dispatches an action and that updates `this.props.data` causing a re-render that works fine.

Comment: hi, how about this, you measure the length of the collection message, when it changes scrollIntoView to false, then you prepare a button to notify the user if there is a new message, for example '2 new message' when clicked it will be post to post first message